# on delete cascade is deleting entire child table

Tags: sql-server, parent-child, cascade

I have two tables:
Parent, which has a primary key (parentID) and some other fields of type varchar(50) and Child which is as follows:

```
childID, primary key
parentID, foreign key references Parent (parentID)
otherID, foreign key  to another table
```

- If I delete a row from Child, no problem.
- If I delete a row from Parent, I get a foreign key constraint error on Child -- good, that's correct.

Now, I modify the relationship for the parentID key and set delete to cascade instead of No Action
(I'm using the 2008 server studio, right-clicking on column, choose Modify, then right click on the table design and choose Relationships.  I then choose the relationship for the Parent/Child tables and open the Insert/Update Specification section under Table Designer)

If I delete a row from Child, again, no problem.
If I delete a row from Parent, ALL the rows of the child table are deleted, even through most of them point to other parentIDs.

I inherited this DB and all it's tables.  Is there some properties settings I'm missing?  From what I've read, the cascade delete should ONLY delete the child rows that point to the single parentID I deleted from Parent.

Thanks.

Ben

Comment: Yes, cascade delete will only delete the child rows associated with the parent. My best guess is that you haven't defined cascade delete right. Check that again.

Answer (score 2):

Right, the delete should only delete rows related to the deleted "parent".

Take a look at the cascading delete setup, and also look for triggers that may be incorrectly written.

Comment: Excellent point about the triggers. And personally I'm not in favor of ever using on cascade delete.

Comment: That was it, thanks!  There was a trigger function that, on it's own, wasn't doing anything, but in conjunction with the cascade delete was cleaning out the table.

Comment: @ben: NP.  @HLGEM: I agree--cascading deletes are (usually) a bad idea.  I think there are cases where they don't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting SetNull instead of cascade, which results setting your child table column (where Parent Table's key exit) to *NULL*.